# Can I generate custom Dwolla buttons for each of my users with just their Dwolla ID and my Application Key

Tags: dwolla

So my web application will have users, and each user has customers. Each customer has their own customer page where they can see and pay the user any remaining balance on their account.

I want to create "Pay Now" buttons that link to the user's Dwolla account, and return the customer back to my site after they have submitted the payment. I don't want to make each user generate their own button though. Is there any I can generate a button for them with my own application key and their Dwolla ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use Dwolla payment buttons for scenario.  You can simply integrate with our Off-Site Gateway API.  Check out the Server-to-Server workflow [here](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/gateway#server-to-server).

Essentially, your webapp will POST to Dwolla some details about the checkout you’re trying to create (destination, amount, etc.) and Dwolla will respond with a CheckoutId.

From there, you'll use the CheckoutId to construct a URL which you'll send the user off to by means of a redirect or a link.

[Here](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/gateway#ux)'s a demo of what this flow would look like to a user.